# Using service account to copy the apps

Tags: sudo, scp

Currently we are having Git repository which is configured with srvapps (service account).I can sudo to the Git server using this account (username - srvapps and password - my login password).

My application is running on the username "srvapps" and all the directories is owned by the srvapps:srvapps (username/group)

But for some reason, if do scp from my git server to application server to copy the new files, it says permission denied.

From my Git server - I have used following commands -

```
scp -r new_file srvapps@app1:\home_git\apps - Its asking for srvapps password.

scp -r new_file myuserid@app1:\home_git\apps - It says permission denied.
```

Could you pls let me know, what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: Your description is very poorly worded, I have read it 5 times and am still unclear what you're a) trying to achieve and b) why being prompted for a password is a problem.

Comment: Sorry for the bad description.

Comment: Basically, I have Git server. I make the configuration changes on the Git server and then i need to copy the changes it to the App server.  when i copy it (as explained above), its either asking for password or says permission denied. a) - i need to copy the files from git server to app server.  b) service account (srvapps) doesnt have password. So i dont know what password to put. Also, when  i used my_login_id, it says permission denied. The owner (user) of the git directory is srvapps.  The directory which i need to copy, owner (user) is srvapps

Comment: On the app server - can you ssh to the app server as yourself? And become the service account?

Comment: I cant ssh in to the box with the srvapps account (sudo ssh srvapps@appserver1. but if i login to the server, first with my account then i can use sudo su - srvapps and login as the service account user.

Comment: Well, then do it that way round; log into the app server, become the service account, and scp from remote to local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ssh into the app server, become the app user
`sudo su - srvapps`

Then copy across from git server 
`scp -r myuserid@git:/path/to/files .`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did some research as well. I didnt find any other solution. Also, the problem is that before copying the files i need to login to other server all the time (we have nearly 30 servers in 5 tiers) each tier has different set of code. The other option is to use, ssh keys.

Comment: That would be a sensible solution. Or you could use ansible - but those are things you could have mentioned in your question to get a better response ... ;)